# Probability to draw two particular cards from a deck.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Given is a deck of 52 cards and the question is, what is the probability to draw an 8 and a Q (drawn without replacement).

Here is what I did:

The sample space should be $52 \choose 2$. Since for the first card, say a 8 we have 4 possibilities and for the other card we also have 4 possibilities, the probability should be :

$$
P=\frac{16}{52 \choose 2} \approx 0.01207
$$

This is unfortunately wrong, the correct answer is given approximately to be $0.0264$.

I would appreciate your help, especially an explanation why my solution is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your source for this "correct" answer is right?  Your answer seems correct to me.

Comment: It comes form a textbook, therefore I assume it is. Actually this is why I asked the question, to see what the experts on the forum have to say about it.

Comment: It's half the right answer; he's only got the probability for 8Q, and needs in addition the probability for Q8.  But that still falls short of the stated answer of $0.0264$.  I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: @BrianTung He has the correct answer.

Comment: Your answer is right. I suggest that you double check the problem statement. Are we taking two cards?

Comment: Yes we are talking two cards (Q and 8), the suite is not specified.

Comment: @Rori: It's right if the 8 has to come before the Q.  If they can come in either order he has to double his answer, doesn't he?

Comment: @BrianTung The order of Q8 does not matter as long as he assumes that the order of any two cards does not matter either (52 choose 2). With your method one would have to assume that the order of any two cards also mattered, if the order of Q8 matter, which still yields the same result.

Comment: Yes, never mind, I had a brain fade.

Comment: Occasionally, the answers in textbooks are wrong. This appears to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four Queens and four eights, so you could draw a Queen then an eight or the other way round, making the probability $$2 \times \frac4{52} \times \frac{4}{51}$$ which is your answer.

Comment: Your answer is the same as OP's.

Comment: That's the answer OP already gave.

Comment: Indeed it is the same.  Or half this is the eight has to come before the queen

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and the book is wrong.   The rule of thumb for frequentistic measures is: as above, so too below. (With regards to counting combinations or permutations.)

- There are $\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}$ ways to select 1 of 4 eights and 1 of 4 queens.
- There are $\binom{52}{2}$ ways to select 2 of 52 cards.
- Order is not considered in either count.   It need not be.
- If there is no bias in the selection of cards then the probability is:$$\frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 1}{52\cdot 51} \approx 0.012{\small (06...)}$$

---

- There are $\binom{4}{1}\cdot\binom{4}{1}\cdot 2!$ distinctly ordered ways to select 1 of 4 eights and 1 of 4 queens.
- There are $\binom{52}{2}\cdot 2!$ distinctly ordered ways to select 2 of 52 cards.
- Order is considered in both count.   It cancels.
- If there is no bias in the selection of cards then the probability is:$$\require{cancel}\frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 1\cancel{\cdot 2!}}{52\cdot 51\cancel{\cdot 2!}} \approx 0.012{\small (06...)}$$

Comment: Thank you for including the example with the ordered set.